# Django custom template tag throwing an error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters, templatetags

I am trying to use a custom template tag and it gives me this error when I am trying to get a rendered page:

`Invalid block tag on line 29: 'get_message_print_tag', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

I am trying to get a simple title for my flash messages based on `{{message.tags}}` and make it bold in my template. Where am I making a mistake?

**apptags.py:**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


def get_message_print_tag(value):
    '''return a string for a message tag depending on the
        message tag that can be displayed bold on the flash message''' 
    if 'danger' in value.lower():
        return 'ERROR'
    elif 'success' in value.lower():
        return 'SUCCESS'
    else:
        return 'NOTE'
```

**html:**

```
{% load apptags %}

        <div class="bootstrap-iso">
        {% if messages %}
            <div class="messages ">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div {% if message.tags %} class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" {% endif %}>
                        {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Error: {% endif %}


                        <strong> {% get_message_print_tag {{message.tags}} %}  </strong>
                        {{ message }}
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>

                    </div>
                {% endfor %}            
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Django documentation: [Simple Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

To ease the creation of tags that take a number of arguments – strings or template variables – and return a result after doing some processing based solely on the input arguments and some external information, Django provides a helper function, `simple_tag`. This function, which is a method of `django.template.Library`, takes a function that accepts any number of arguments, wraps it in a render function and the other necessary bits mentioned above and registers it with the template system.

So the problem was only one line which should be above the definition of the tag:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_message_print_tag(value):
    '''return a string for a message tag depending on the
        message tag that can be displayed bold on the flash message''' 
    if 'danger' in value.lower():
        return 'ERROR'
    elif 'success' in value.lower():
        return 'SUCCESS'
    else:
        return 'NOTE'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the decorator `@register.simple_tag` to the function and use it this way:

```
{% get_message_print_tag message.tags %}
```

instead of

```
{% get_message_print_tag {{message.tags}} %}
```

Comment: I have tried this and I am still getting the same error

Comment: Even when I replace `{{ message.tags }}` with `'success'` it throws the same error, which means what you mentioned is not the issue

Comment: what you pointed was a problem too though, I realized it after solving the first problem!

Comment: Yes you are right `@register.simple_tag` is also missing. Will update the answer accordingly.